# Is there a standard way of addig HSTS header to embedded jetty Servlet?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a custom Servlet implementation that extends HttpServlet. Is there a standard way to add the HSTS header to the response?

The only way I found is adding

```
response.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains")
```

But then I need to do the same for all of the methods. Is there a simpler way?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I use an embedded jetty server

Edit2: Apparently it looks like the HeaderFilter class can be used to do this, and the add the filter to the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.

- A traditional Servlet `Filter`.
  Be aware of `DispatcherType` behaviors, and what do you want to do if anything when the response is reset, or you are in a flow that isn't `DispatcherType.REQUEST` (eg: async, error, include, forward, etc)
- Override the `HttpServlet.service()` method to add the header and then delegate to the normal service flow.
- Create a new `RewriteHandler` `Rule` to do that for you.
- Create a new Jetty `Handler` that adds the header and then proceeds through the handler chain to your web app (at a later point in the handler chain)
- Create a `HttpConfiguration.Customizer` implementation to do that for you once the request has been parsed, and before it is dispatched to your web application.
- Create an `HttpChannel.Listener` that adds the headers to the response on `onResponseBegin()` events.